# populating a bootstrap html table via jquery data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i just buil a data APIT trough Kimono -> https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/2ewmh21u?apikey=lvafgzGqR6fOqrI0mXAbiPEmQGh7rR4m.
i would like to include it in a simple and nice bootstrap table, like this: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html.

i just tried to insert the jquery code given by kimono

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function kimonoCallback(data) {
// do something with the data
// please make sure the scope of this function is global
}

$.ajax({
"url":"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/2ewmh21u?apikey=lvafgzGqR6fOqrI0mXAbiPEmQGh7rR4m&callback=kimonoCallback",
"crossDomain":true,
"dataType":"jsonp"
});
 </script>
```

but i didn't manage to create the table.
any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can active bootstrap table via javascript:

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="nome" data-formatter="linkFormatter">Nome</th>
      <th data-field="descrizione" data-formatter="linkFormatter">Descrizione</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<script>
function linkFormatter(value) {
  return '<a href="' + value.href + '">' + value.text + '</a>';
}

function kimonoCallback(data) {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data.results.collection1
  });
}

$.ajax({
  "url":"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/2ewmh21u?apikey=lvafgzGqR6fOqrI0mXAbiPEmQGh7rR4m&callback=kimonoCallback",
  "crossDomain":true,
  "dataType":"jsonp"
});
 </script>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/8svjf80g/33/

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you want to display from your JSONP feed, but generally you can handle the display like so:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Href</th>
      <th>Text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="loadHere">
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function kimonoCallback(data) {
  // this will help you see data structure while you develop the table
  console.log(data);
  // then create your table
  var results = data.results.collection1,
     i;
  for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
    $('#loadHere').append(
      '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + results[i].nome.href + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + results[i].nome.text + '</td>' +
      '<td>' +
    '</table>');
  }
}

$.ajax({
"url":"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/2ewmh21u?apikey=lvafgzGqR6fOqrI0mXAbiPEmQGh7rR4m&callback=kimonoCallback",
"crossDomain":true,
"dataType":"jsonp"
});
 </script>
```

Be sure to look at the console to see how the data is structured so you can determine which fields to populate the table with.

Answer (score -1):

Well.. You need to actually make the table when `kimonoCallback` gets called.

See?

```
// do something with the data
// please make sure the scope of this function is global
```